# Adding test users to private Yodlee sandbox

Tags: yodlee

I've looked on the Yodlee website but I can't see any documentation on how best to do test and development.

We have been allocated a private sandbox for testing but the API does not allow adding users. There doesn't seem a way to add them either so it seems pretty pointless.

I registered on the developer portal and got our code working with the test users generated there but this expired after 30 days so is not a viable option for continued testing.

Is there a way to add users to the private sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have been allocated a private sandbox for testing they you can use [register3](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/register3) API to add test users and then continue with your testing.

Comment: Thanks, I did realise that after posting. What confused me is that it tells you it isn't available when using TestDrive.

Comment: TestDrive was meant to be used with developer portal credentials and hence it's blocked in that.